# Why am I getting an infinite loop? [PYTHON 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I am trying to run a very basic while loop and am still new to python I have learned obviously:

```
numbers = []
def print_numbers(x):
    i = 0
    counter = x
    while i < counter:
        print "top of the list"
        numbers.append(i)
        print i 
        i += 1    
        #print "Numbers nows:", numbers
        #print"At the bottom i is %d" % i

#print "The numbers:"
y = raw_input("Pleast enter the number:")
print_numbers(y)
#for num in numbers:
#    print num
```

So, this loop does what it says it does, takes a number and add's it to the list one at a time, the length of the list is defined by user input. Seem straight forward enough correct. Well when I run it I get an infinite loop. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `y` variable is of type `str`, so it's never less than `i`. You need to parse it as an `int` after reading it from stdin.

```
numbers = []


def print_numbers(x):
    i = 0
    counter = x
    print i,counter
    while i < counter:
        print "top of the list"
        numbers.append(i)
        print i
        i += 1
        # print "Numbers nows:", numbers
        # print"At the bottom i is %d" % i


# print "The numbers:"
y = int(raw_input("Pleast enter the number:"))
print_numbers(y)
```